# iOS Screen Capture is blurry

Tags: ios, screen, image-capture

I am having trouble getting a screen shot that is not blurry - first I tried this:

[Screen capture for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253204/screen-capture-for-ios)

and it was not blurry but I think Apple will not let this code through - won't make the review?

so I went with the official solution in the developer docs: similar to this:
[Capturing Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429854/capturing-screen)

But when I use the 'official' way, the image it creates is blurry

Here is the code I am using straight from the dev support docs (iOS6 and I am scaling it, but there is no difference if scale is 0):

```
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.65);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Iterate over every window from back to front
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];


        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();



UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

Comment: Why `0.65`? Change it to `0`. Also, didn't find anything in the first link that uses a private API, which solution were you talking about?

Comment: 0.65 to keep the image size smaller - this image posts to FB and Twitter and at 0 scale it is too big...

Comment: the first solution I had: was     CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);

Comment: Don't do that.  Take it at the correct scale, and then render it again into a preferable size.

Comment: OK.. I am thinking of CGContextScaleCTM(context, .6, .6);   but don't know where in the code to put it - thx

Comment: so just clear a little doubt that whether you want blury image or not?

Comment: I do not want a blurry image -

Answer (score 3):

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale)` allows you to create graphic bitmap context which supports high resolution screens by applying *scale factor*.

If you specify a value of 0.0 then the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen. On a standard-resolution screen, the scale factor is typically 1.0. On a high-resolution screen, the scale factor is typically 2.0.

In your case you specify the value of 0.65

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.65);
```

So some blurring effect occurs

---

You can get complete information about using scale factor in [iOS Drawing Concepts Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) **Points Versus Pixels**

Comment: Thanks voromax - to be clear, if I'm running a hi-res screen, is the image 0.65 of 2.0?

Comment: I've added a link to the corresponding guide. What size in pixels do you want the screenshot to be?