# iOS screen capture is blurry for some reason

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, screenshot

I'm trying to capture the screen inside of my app, it used to work just great, but now I only get a blurry image. like that:

[image: blurry screen capture]

This is my code:

```
- (UIImage *)takeScreenShotWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);
    }
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Screen Capture is blurry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849944/ios-screen-capture-is-blurry)

Comment: That is a very useless if condition.

Comment: On which iOS versions are you having this issue?

Comment: I'm having this issue in iOS7, it's actually crash in iOS6 because of drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates. I want it to work in iOS6-iOS7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

Try:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
```